# Why is Prolog not recognizing these built-ins?

Tags: prolog

I'm having trouble using the `round/1` and `floor/1` built-ins in SWI-Prolog. When using them in my code, they aren't recognized and when submitting them as a query; for instance `?- round(1.6).`, Prolog will tell me that the procedure is not recognized. Am I doing something wrong? I tried it on both the online Swish version and my own windows installed version, but getting the same error on both.

Answer (score 1):

**`round/1` and `floor/1` are no builtin predicates, `round/2` and `floor/2` are**.

Prolog works with predicates. That means that a predicate can only be `true` or `false` (or error). Furthermore it can unify variables (further).

So the only means to calculate the `floor` of 1.6, is to use two variables, and make the second one the floor of the first one. For example:

```
?- round(1.6,X).
X = 2.

?- floor(1.6,X).
X = 1.
```

Since it is sometimes cumbersome to write predicates that way. Prolog has defined some *functors*, these functors can be interpreted with the `is/2` predicate. `round/1` and `floor/1` are functors with semantics in the `is/2` predicate:

```
?- X is round(1.6).
X = 2.

?- X is floor(1.6).
X = 1.
```

`is` can work with more advanced expression trees as well, like:

```
?- X is floor(0.4+0.4+0.4).
X = 1.
```

But note that `is` is actually a predicate as well. We have written:

```
is(X, floor(0.4+0.4+0.4)).
```

behind the curtains, and the `is/2` predicate will call `floor/2`. Mind however that you can not simply inject your own predicate that way. You can not simply write `is(X, foo(2))` and expect Prolog to call `foo(2.X)`.

Comment: *Since it is sometimes cumbersome to write predicates that way, you can also write it as:...* I'd be careful here. You're potentially leaving the impression that any predicate of the form, `functor(..., X)` can also be expressed as `X is functor(...)` which obviously isn't universally true. It suggests any predicate has a functional form. It also isn't always true for all arithmetic functions. For example, you can write `X is min(2,3).` and get `X = 2`. But `min(2,3,X)` fails since `min/3` doesn't exist.

Comment: I think the definition of *functor* is too specific. For a term of the form `foo(...)` with arguments, `foo` is referred to as a *functor*. It isn't specific to arithmetic functions. I would probably say that certain built-in predicates in Prolog are *arithmetic functions* and, therefore, can be used with `is/2` as well as other arithmetic operators (*e.g.*, `>/2`). I'm not sure I would say that the alternate form is because the other form is "cumbersome" (they're both about the same amount of typing). They're just alternatives. One is explicitly used as an arithmetic function. The other not.